# $(".class").width($(this)...) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of `div`s with, let's say, the `.class` class. And I need to assign them a width based on an specific route

```
$(".class").width($(this).parent().next().find("code").width())
```

But, for some reason, it doesn't work with `$(this)` but it does when I do this:

```
$(".class").width($(".class").parent().next().find("code").width())
```

but obviously only for the first one. Any clue?

Comment: With $("this") or it'd work with ...each($(".class")...)?

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to in `$(".class").width($(this).parent().next().find("code").width())`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method accepts a function:

> A function returning the width to set. Receives the index position of
>   the element in the set and the old width as arguments. Within the
>   function, this refers to the current element in the set.

```
$(".class").width(function () {
    return $(this).parent().next().find("code").width()
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Never knew `.width()` could take a function as a parameter. Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 1):

Since classes are meant to be used on multiple elements, your jQuery selector is probably returning a set of elements rather than a single element. Additional jQuery operations such as `.width()` on a set of matched elements are only executed on the first match. Therefore you'll need to iterate over the matched set of elements in order to complete the function for each match.

```
$('.class').each(function (idx, elem) {
    // Returns the width
    // Not sure what the intention is here. Assign to variable maybe?
    return $(elem).parent().next().find('code').width();
});
```

Comment: @smerny Apologies. Typed too fast. Good catch. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling these functions, there is no reason why `this` should point to each individual `.class` elements. You are in global context (of whatever), but not in the context of `.class` DOMElement.

You can use `each` method instead:

```
$(".class").each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).parent().next().find("code").width());
});
```

or `width` method providing a function as a setter:

```
$(".class").width(function() {
    return $(this).parent().next().find("code").width();
});
```

Both methods will loop through every element in collection `$('.class')` and invoke callback functions in the context of every element.